# How to Fade in AFTER the Page has Loaded: Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I am using a fade effect script to fade in my home page, but ideally, I'd like to start the fade once the background image has been loaded.

How could I incorporate this into my existing javascript?

**UPDATED Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    if (window.localStorage && !localStorage['faded']) {
        localStorage['faded'] = true;
        $('body').hide().fadeIn(500);
    }
});
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
    background: #000;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: black url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat 200px center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: 2.8 seconds is a really long time to wait for a page. I bring this up only because I bet some users will find it frustrating. Especially if they already have to wait for a giant background image to load. You might consider shortening your fadeIn.

Comment: I've continued [this topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248387/is-using-a-fade-effect-on-page-considered-excessive-in-terms-of-design-load-time). Hopefully I can gain more insight from the users here, and weigh the pros/cons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $(window).load instead of $(document).ready - [the difference](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/) is that the latter will run after all your assets are loaded including images.

Comment: That is a simple solution. He might want to set body to `display:none` on document ready though, or else the body will disappear once the background finally loads only to fade back in. For accessibility he definitely would not want to hide the body through CSS.

Comment: I haven't noticed the body disappearing. Is this a potential flaw that just hasn't shown itself yet?

Comment: @kurzweilguy If you clear your cache or do a hard reload you should notice the difference. `$(window).load` will not fire until everything in the page, including images, has loaded. Depending on the size and amount of your assets, this event can fire a few seconds after the page renders; especially on a slow internet connection. If `body` has not already been hidden with CSS it will only hide after the background image and such have loaded, then immediately fade back in.

Comment: @Elimn: I've updated the script (to include cache), but I've noticed that the `body` loads directly, and then everything goes black and fades in. What did I do wrong, here? Also, I'm against hiding the page with CSS

Comment: Neither $(window).load nor $(document).ready can work reliably if the background is already set via css. Because technically if your background is already cached, it can be shown before $(document).ready. The event to trigger a fadein to an image or background already set on an element would be the 'interactive' readyState. jQuery relies on the 'complete' state for $(document).ready due to IE9-10 bugs/misfire of the 'interactive' event. Even with the 'interactive' state, there are case where window.onload fires almost immediately after 'complete', which can prevent you from doing a fadeIn.