# Is Using a Fade In Effect on Page Considered Excessive in Terms of Design/Load Time?

Tags: jquery, css

Is this poor practice in web design? (the whole fade-in thing) I've gotten some mixed reviews from users on here that say it's excessive. What's the consensus? I would like to follow common practices and steer clear of any faux pas.

I realize that it's a very subtle thing, and I could live without it... but, it adds something to the design, in my opinion.

The big concern is this: Does it deter some users? I don't have a fall-back for when the user doesn't have Javascript enabled, but the page still shows. That shouldn't be an issue, but does the effect itself turn people away?

What would be considered "too long" for the effect to load/complete? Some have said that 2.8 seconds is too long for a lot of users. Is there some type of common accepted value?

**Addendum:** I've noticed that most sites don't use this sort of effect. Is this because of longer load times being undesirable, or is the visual effect just annoying?

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.body.style.display = 'none';
        $('body').fadeIn(2800);
    })
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
    background: #000;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: black url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat 200px center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: 2,800ms is waaaay to long to fade something in—especially your **entire page**.  That's going to get old **very** quickly for your users.  I'd urge you to drop the fade time way down - 500ms max, maybe less.

Comment: They'll take that as taking another 2.8 seconds to be able to use that site - most likely they'll just leave.

Comment: Why in the name of _Atwood_ would you ever intentionally make a page load more slowly for such a flamboyant purpose? **Don't do it.** If I experienced this when visiting a site, I would _never_ go back.

Comment: 3 second is enough for a user to decide whether to stay or leave the page. Use a bit fast fadeIn if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are asking for our opinion on having the page fade in on load, I think that there are a few things to consider

## Pros

- Useful for certain animated pages/projects
- Would work very well if you could cache the site so it only fades on first page load
- By using `$(document).ready`, the user won't have to see any part of the site not loaded

## Cons

- Would most likely load on every refresh/visit of the page, which would deter a user
- 2.8 seconds is quite a long time
- By using `$(document).ready`, if there is any part of the site that hasn't loaded, then this page won't load, and the user might assume the page is broken, steering them away from the page

Overall, I think that it definitely depends on the situation that you are in, but it most likely is not the best solution to what you want to do

To answer the question of "How long is too long?", I would say that in most cases, I use `.5` seconds, and at max I have used `1` second

Most sites don't use this function because users don't get upset if a site doesn't transition in neatly, because they are used to the page appearing. And if an `img` happens to not load, then they will automatically leave your site

Comment: This is the type of insight I've been looking for! Thanks guys!